# Vector of shared_ptr gives seg fault when instances in vector accessed

Tags: c++, vector, shared-ptr

I have a vector of `shared_ptr<SomeClass>` named `allParts`.

The code is like below:

```
void function thisIsWhereItStarts(){
    vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass> > allParts;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        allParts.push_back(function_which_returns_shared_ptr_someclass());
    }

// Then I use this vector as below:  
    for(vector<shared_ptr<SomeClass> >::iterator it = allParts.begin(); it!=allParts.end(); it++){
         (*it)->function_of_SomeClass() ; // THIS GIVES SEGMENTATION FAULT
    }
}
```

I've used vector of pointers a number of times before, but this is the first time I'm using `shared_ptr` .

The function which returns the `shared_ptr` is like this:

```
shared_ptr<SomeClass> function_which_returns_shared_ptr_someclass(){

    shared_ptr<SomeClass> part(new SomeClass);
    if(part->some_function(some_parameter)){
         return part;
    }else{
         return shared_ptr<SomeClass>();
    }

}
```

Comment: How does `function_which_returns_shared_ptr_someclass()` look like?

Comment: The bug lies in code not shown, quite possibly in the function that returns the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. I should not have to tell that to someone with >1k rep.

Comment: From the code provided it doesn not seem that usage of shared_ptr is justified.

Comment: I've made edits to the question. I'm sorry I didn't include stuff earlier that I presumed was not relevant.. Included that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You `push_back` even an empty `shared_ptr`. Then you dereference every `shared_ptr` in the vector. Dereferencing an empty `shared_ptr` will fail. Either don't `push_back` the empty pointers or don't dereference them.

Comment: Short, but functional.

Comment: Thanks. Failed to notice that. I added a null check on the pointer before dereferencing it.